# check if the value of the input field changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field where the value is populated using a modal, simply when i click a button a modal will appear and i will select something there and it will populate my input field.

now my problem is that I want to trigger an event whenever the value of my input field changes. I already tried using .change and .blur but it wont trigger.

this is all I tried:

```
$('#myTextbox').on('input', function() {
    alert("test");
});

$('#myTextbox').on('change', function() {
    alert("test");
});

$('#myTextbox').on('blur', function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: So how do you change input value??? If setting it using code, then you need to trigger event manualy

Comment: @A.Wolff what do you mean by event manually? sorry this is my first time hearing that term

Comment: e.g: `$('#myTextbox').val('something').trigger('input');`  so in fact i meant programatically instead of manually. But if you had provided minimalistic sample replicating issue in question itself, your issue would already has been fixed. This would at least avoided many confusion because it is not really clear what you are asking

Comment: would this be placed inside the modal js for populating the input field? I can't change anything on that part. I can only create my own function to check when the field is populated or changed. thats the best I can do actually since its a bit of a lengthy html and I just wanted to give the gist of things.

Comment: This modal probaly exposes some event or you can bind your own event to modal elements. Again, try to provide MCVE with minimalistic relevant code and it would be easier to find a relevant answer

Comment: @A.Wolff maybe i can just check when the modal is closed to trigger the event. the modal JS is already a default and we cannot edit it as it is already in the CRM so the most we can do is to create our own custom javascripts and attached them to the edit page

Comment: Ya, on modal close event, check if value changed and if so trigger any relevant event on this input. And on modal open, save current input value so you can compare it on modal close, if it has changed or not

Comment: Press F12 on chrome it shows consoleLog()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `event delegation`

You question says that you input field is generated dynamically. So it was not in the DOM when your page gets ready.

```
$('body').on('blur', '#myTextbox', function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

FYI, you can use `change` as well.

**EDIT**

One solution you can use `setTimeout` till your text-box gets value populated.

**OR**

You can try with `DOMAttrModified`

```
$('body').on('DOMAttrModified propertychange paste', '#myTextbox', function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

[Reference](http://help.dottoro.com/ljfvvdnm.php#additionalEvents)

Comment: `blue` event didn't fired on input change. You should use `change` event.

Comment: I don't think it is OP's issue. I guess he changes an input value programatically from some modal input

Comment: im sorry for confusing you, the value is added using js not the field it self

Comment: @hungrykoala : I've updated my answer, try it, it may works for you.

Comment: Is everything ok ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTextbox').on('blur', function() {
        alert("test");
    });
});

OR

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTextbox').on('change', function() {
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

Comment: it is already inside document ready and it is still not being triggered. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this, might be your `input` field is populating at run time, that's why the event is not firing.

```
$(document).on('change blur keyup', '#myTextbox', function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

You can bind all the event in one `.on()` method. No need write no of times.